# unable to read using SelectSinglenode in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a below Address xml and i am trying to read the the property node in c# and i am getting the null in propertyAddress .
can some body can help me in this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REQUEST_GRP>
    <REQUESTCRD LoginAccountIdentifier="DQ892481" LoginAccountPassword="892481" />
        <REQUESTDATA>
            <INFORMATION_REQUEST>
                 <_PROPERTY _StreetAddress = "7805 FLR CT"
                     _StreetAddress2 = ""
                      _City = "" 
                     _State = "" 
                     _County = "" 
                     _PostalCode = "88888">
            </INFORMATION_REQUEST>
        </REQUESTDATA>
</REQUEST_GRP>

<add key="XProperty" value="REQUEST_GRP/REQUESTCRD/REQUESTDATA/INFORMATION_REQUEST/_PROPERTY"/>
```

c# code:

```
 XmlElement propertyAddress = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode(this["XProperty"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use LINQ:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 XElement prop = doc.Descendants("_PROPERTY").First();
```